# Why Child is not Appearing in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to add a child in .cs file to a Stack Layout created in the file .xaml

The Stack Layout in .xaml file is this:

```
 <StackLayout Margin="10" x:Name="TypeStack">
```

While, in the .cs file I'm calling the StackLayout named TypeStack in this way:

```
 TypeStack.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
```

and it works because the background color is changed.
But when I try to add a child, the child is not appear:

```
 var stack = new StackLayout {
     BackgroundColor = Color.Green
 };

 TypeStack.Children.Add(stack);
```

Could you help me to solve this problem?
Reading the documentation, I've red that this is the way to add a child.
Waiting for you response,
thank you in advance.

Comment: Add WidthRequest, HeightRequest or HorizontalOptions, VerticalOptions property to new stack which was added in code.

Comment: `stack` is a container without any content so it will not display.  Add some content to it